# trouble when downloading and building webrtcdemoapp for android

Tags: android, svn

When I download the webrtcdemo code for android using the command "gclient sync --nohook"
I get the following

```
[0:53:34] Still working on:

[0:53:34]   trunk/third_party/android_tools

Syncing projects:  97% (48/49), done.
```

gclient does not sync the project 100%
Then I give the  command

```
cd trunk

 ./build/install-build-deps-android.sh

 . ./build/android/envsetup.sh 

 gclient runhooks 

 android_gyp
```

I get the following things

```
Please call build/gyp_chromium instead. android_gyp is going away.
Updating projects from gyp files...
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/ui/views/examples/examples.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/ui/message_center/message_center.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/third_party/webrtc/tools/tools.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/ui/wm/wm.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/apps/shell/app_shell.gyp not found (cwd: 

gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/ui/views/views.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/ui/views/controls/webview/webview.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/tools/xdisplaycheck/xdisplaycheck.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/third_party/libevent/libevent.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/sandbox/sandbox.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/dbus/dbus.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/courgette/courgette.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/chrome/tools/profile_reset/jtl_compiler.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/breakpad/breakpad.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/ui/aura/aura.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/v8/tools/gyp/v8.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/tools/telemetry/telemetry.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/tools/perf/clear_system_cache/clear_system_cache.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/third_party/ots/ots.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/third_party/npapi/npapi.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/third_party/modp_b64/modp_b64.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/third_party/mesa/mesa.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/third_party/lzma_sdk/lzma_sdk.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/third_party/libxslt/libxslt.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/third_party/libwebp/libwebp.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/third_party/qcms/qcms.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/third_party/libpng/libpng.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/third_party/libusb/libusb.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/third_party/iccjpeg/iccjpeg.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/webkit/renderer/compositor_bindings/compositor_bindings_tests.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/third_party/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/third_party/cacheinvalidation/cacheinvalidation.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/third_party/WebKit/public/all.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/third_party/codesighs/codesighs.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/skia/skia.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/printing/printing.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/ppapi/tools/ppapi_tools.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/ppapi/ppapi_internal.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/ppapi/ppapi.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/mojo/mojo.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/media/media.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/media/cast/cast.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/jingle/jingle.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/ipc/ipc.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/gpu/tools/tools.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/gpu/gpu.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/gin/gin.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/device/usb/usb.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/device/device_tests.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/device/bluetooth/bluetooth.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/cc/cc_tests.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/chrome/chrome.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/third_party/re2/re2.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/sync/sync.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/content/content_shell_and_tests.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/url/url.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
gyp: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk/ui/snapshot/snapshot.gyp not found (cwd: /home/tata/WebRTC-Android/webrtcdemo/trunk)
```

Please help, Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to the problem?